# Getting a binding error when trying to run Node http server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

We are supposed to create a simple http node server that should respond to a root-url request with a file called index.html. Do not use ExpressJS. Code should have error checking and at least one callback. Put five or more html elements in your index.html. One of the elements should be a link to an external page.

This is the code I have:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs   = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');


var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

fs.exists(index, function(exists) {
     try {
       if(exists) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write("<html>");
  response.write("<head>");
  response.write("<title>Hello World!</title>");
  response.write("</head>");
  response.write("<body>");
  response.write("<div>");
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.write("</div>");
  response.write("<a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Google</a>")
  response.write("</body>");
  response.write("</html>");
        } else {
         response.writeHead(500);
        }
    } finally {
         response.end(index);
    }
 });
});
 
server.listen(80);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

And I am getting this binding error:

Server is listening

```
fs.js:166
  binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path), cb);
          ^
TypeError: path must be a string
    at Object.fs.exists (fs.js:166:11)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/rahulsharma/Desktop/server.js:8:4)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2112:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1970:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the index variable with 'index.html' will do the job but

please Do NOT use fs.exists , read its API doc
http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm a tad confused -- isn't fs.exists used to test is file path is true or not? Reading through the API, nothing suggests otherwise?

Comment: In node , the program doesn't give a error when a file doesn't exist in fact it sets the variable to undefined. So while reading the file with fs.readFileSync() if the index is set to undefined , it doesn't exist else u know what to do .

Answer (score 0):

Place the index.html with the .js file. Put all the html in that file.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs   = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile("index.html",function(err,content){
        if(err){
            throw err;
            console.log("Error reading index file.");
            res.send("Aw snap!");
        }
        else{
            res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/HTML"});
            res.end(content,"UTF-8");
        }
    });
});
server.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to you stack trace the error is inside this line:

```
fs.exists(index, function(exists)
```

What you pass to this function(which checks if given file exists) is actually content of the file. What you should pass as first argument is probably `"index.html"` instead of `index` variable

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call [fs.exists](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) which expects a string path and you are giving it a filehandler index.
That's why the error is:

```
path must be a string
```

Either try using the string "index.html" and do not read it sync there. Do it async in the exists callback

```
fs.exists("index.htm", function(){ fs.readFile("index.htm")
```